# Appnext kotlin integration

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to try Appnext ads in my app but there is no official documentation to help me achieve this, can someone please help me with this?

```
Appnext.init(context);
BannerView bannerView = (BannerView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
bannerView.loadAd(new BannerAdRequest());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var banner: BannerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        // Initialize the SDK
        Appnext.init(this)
        banner = BannerView(this)

        // Load the Banner
        val bannerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.banner) as BannerView
        bannerView.loadAd(BannerAdRequest())
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        banner.destroy()
    }
}
```

Currently, there's is no documentation in Kotlin for integrating AppNext. Here are links for [integrating](https://developers.appnext.com/docs/android-sdk-installation) the SDK and for [using](https://developers.appnext.com/docs/appnext-android-banners) AppNext in Java. You can always write the code in Java then convert to Kotlin. To convert a java file to kotlin: *Menu* > *Code* > *Convert Java File to Kotlin File* OR use `Ctrl+Shift+A` (windows) || ⇧⌘A (mac) then type `convert java file to kotlin file`. Also, take a look into [kotlin-extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to avoid using `findViewById`.